# Was Davy Jones' ability to teleport ever explained in-universe?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

When Will Turner is captured by Davy Jones' men, he tells Davy Jones that he was sent by Jack Sparrow to settle a debt.  We cut to Jack Sparrow looking at Davy Jones through a telescope, and as he lowers the telescope we see that Jack Sparrow has been teleported to the Flying Dutchman.  We know he possesses the power of teleportation because:

1. Jack later says something to the effect of, "If you would **just
   send me back**, I will find you some souls", and
2. the [Wiki
   article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Jones_(Pirates_of_the_Caribbean)#Powers_and_abilities)
   says so.

Is it ever explained, in-universe, how Davy Jones has come to possess the power of teleportation?  Or is it just something you're supposed to assume after he does it?

Comment: Referring to the wiki article is a matter of circular reasoning. The wiki lists it _because_ it happened. The wiki isn't the reason (nor explanation) _why_ it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears it's just one of many abilities that come with being Captain of the Flying Dutchman...

from [wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Davy_Jones)

> **His position as the captain of the Flying Dutchman and the Ferryman to
>   the Underworld gave Jones his ability to switch between the worlds of
>   the dead and the living. This power was most likely the reason for
>   other supernatural traits of him, including the abilities to teleport
>   himself** and walk through solid objects. Jones was also able to
>   restore the Wicked Wench when he raised the ship from the depths,
>   after it was burned by the East India Trading Company. However, this
>   position had some negative consequences as well: He could not go on
>   land, except for one day in ten years and by abandoning his
>   duty as the ferryman to the afterlife he brought a curse upon himself
>   and his crew which caused their transformation into fish-men. However,
>   he is shown standing on the sandbar with both feet in a bucket of
>   water, indicating that there may be loopholes to not being able to set
>   foot on land.